# How to build a Firestore query with multiple params that returns the best possible result?

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, nosql

I'm building an Android app that allows users to search for others according to multiple parameters (religion, hairstyle, job, origin, age etc...).

I'm using **Firestore** as database. The query is supposed to search a user's collection for document's containing **ALL** keywords entered **OR AS MANY AS POSSIBLE** (in case no document contains all keywords).

The problem is that in case of no document matching perfectly the input (for exp:

**user looked for : Catholic, Short hair, Dancer, American, 38,**

***best possible result*: Catholic, Short hair, Dancer, French, 38**

the query returns no value.

Does anybody knows about a way to solve it ? Thank you

Here's an example of my query :

```
`Query query = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection("users")
                .whereEqualTo("userAge", 38)
                .whereEqualTo("userOrigin", "American")
                .whereEqualTo("userJob", "Dancer")
                .whereEqualTo("userHairStyle", "Short hair")
                .get()`
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! A nice first post, however, it always helps if you list the steps you've taken to try and find a solution to your question. By its nature, you're using `.whereEqualTo()` operators. Therefore, anything NOT EqualTo those values will not come up in the query if it doesn't exist. Try `.whereIn("userOrigin", Arrays.asList("American", "French"));` if you want to include additional options in your query.

Comment: @Ryan C Thank you for your reply. 
Actually after some research I've considered using the `.whereIn()` command but it's not available. 
I'm implementing the latest version of firestore:
`implementation com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:20.2.0`

Answer (score 1):

Firestore doesn't have any "close but not quite" or ranked searches.  All of the constraints must match exactly, or the document will not match.  What you would have to do instead is query for every possible document that *could* match some of your requirements, then decide in the app which one matches the best.